# swapon & hibernate on power key

Tags: linux, systemd, swap, udev, hibernate

I have a laptop & I run Arch Linux. My laptop has a spinning hard drive rather than an SSD, so I hate swap. However, I need one to hibernate, and I want my laptop to hibernate every time power key is pressed or battery runs low. My idea now is to have `swapon` just before `systemd-hibernate.service` starts. (Of course, would be nice to also `swapoff` just after awakening.)

For the purpose, I made a `dev-sda7.swap` unit. Its operation is straightforward:

```
[Unit]

Description=Hibernate swapon
DefaultDependencies=false
TimeoutStopSec=infinity

[Swap]
What=/dev/sda7
```

I hoped to tie it to either `sleep.target`, `hibernate.target` or `systemd-hibernate.service` to have it started just before hibernation and stopped just after. However, things didn't work out so smoothly. For now I have `dev-sda7.swap` stop if I add `PartOf=sleep.target` & I have it start just before `systemd-hibernate.service` if I add `WantedBy=systemd-hibernate.service` & `Before=systemd-hibernate.service`. This sounds like success, but it's not.

`logind.conf` specifies `HandlePowerKey=hibernate` and, as I understand, it invokes `systemctl hibernate`. (Maybe it's more complicated, I don't know.) `systemctl hibernate` however would not issue `start systemd-hibernate.service` unless an integrated swap check is passed, which is not going to happen until `start systemd-hibernate.service` is issued. I hope you can see the complication here.

I'd like to use the logic of `systemd` to have my swap started. So I gather I have to somehow remove the swap check from `logind`. Otherwise, maybe there is a way to run a script just before this check — a script that would `swapon`.

A dedicated `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-lowbat.rules` specifies an arbitrary command to run when power runs low, which can be `systemctl start systemd-hibernate.service`. I wonder if there's an udev rule that runs a command when power key is pressed. I can then do without logind altogether.

What can you advise me?

We had a [conversation of some length on Arch Linux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=225899) that helped establish the evidence but offered no solution.

Comment: Why not just leave swap enabled at all times and adjust swappiness?

Comment: X-Y problem. OP, you have insufficient RAM and instead of fixing the problem you resolve to "hate swap".

Comment: @kubanczyk No, it is not. You are not aware of the particulars of my situation. I am asking a very specific question, am I not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The systemctl swap verification can be disabled by setting `SYSTEMD_BYPASS_HIBERNATION_MEMORY_CHECK=1` for the `systemd-logind` service. This can be done like so:

`# systemctl edit systemd-logind.service`

```
[Service]
Environment=SYSTEMD_BYPASS_HIBERNATION_MEMORY_CHECK=1
```

Now, in order to actually swapon/swapoff when needed, you can add this service:

`# vim /etc/systemd/system/swap-to-hibernate.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Swapon/off when hibernating or resuming
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=systemd-hibernate.service systemd-hybrid-sleep.service
StopWhenUnneeded=yes
RefuseManualStart=yes
RefuseManualStop=yes

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/swapon /dev/sda7    # <--- can be file, too
ExecStop=/usr/bin/swapoff /dev/sda7   

[Install]
RequiredBy=systemd-hibernate.service systemd-hybrid-sleep.service
```

Then just enable it via `# systemctl enable swap-to-hibernate.service`.
You might have to reboot in order for the logind env to take effect, though (maybe `# systemctl daemon-reexec && systemctl reload systemd-logind` will suffice, I'm not sure).

For more info see this systemd [pull request](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/3064) and [this readme](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/doc/ENVIRONMENT.md).

Also, [make sure](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Required_kernel_parameters) the swap kernel parameters are in order (aka resume and resume_offset).